# catch bash script output from expect, expect hangs

Tags: bash, unix, expect

I currently use expect to pass password to rsync to copy files across unix servers

test.sh

```
 ./expect.sh $password rsync -azvr  $username@$host:$file ./$dir
```

expect.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f                                                                                                                                                                                
eval spawn [lrange $argv 1 end]
#expect  "(yes/no)?"                                                                                                                                                                                
#send "yes\r"                                                                                                                                                                                       
expect "*?assword:*"
send [lindex $argv 0]
send \r
interact
```

if server password got changed but not updated in script, I would like to receive a notification.
however currently it would just hangs indefinitely.
If I do the following in test.sh

```
output=`./expect.sh $password rsync -azvr  $username@$host:$file ./$dir`
```

Now the script would hang indefintely so I would never get a chance to handle the output.
how do I solve this issue?

Comment: use ssh pubkey password less or sshpass(less secure)

Answer (score 1):

You should edit your expect script to allow for timeout and expected result after rsync.

For example:

```
...
set timeout 60
expect "*?assword:*"
send [lindex $argv 0]
expect {
 timeout { send_user "\nFatal Error: unable to rsync \n"; exit 1}
 "denied" { send_user "\nFatal Error: unable to rsync \n"; exit 1}
 "sent"
}
```

The above will exit the script in case of 60 second timeout or if received a denied response in case of bad password.  Otherwise if it receives a "sent" text it continues.